# Why does mbufferid sometimes equal 0 in OgreGLES2HardwareBuffer::createBuffer and how to fix it?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, ogre

Ogre.log:
Cannot create GL ES buffer in OgreGLES2HardWareBuffer::createBuffer at OgreGLES2HardWareBuffer.cpp (line 55)

system: huawei matepad pro, hamonyOS 2.0.0

the code in ogre is: glgenbuffer(1, &mbufferid);

mbufferid will sometimes be 0, then run into OGRE_EXCEPT.

But glerror() get no_error.
and I'm sure that glthread is always the same.

How to solve this problem, or why it sometime occur

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have already set ENABLE_GL_CHECK = 1.